# How to prevent dragenter event fires on the draggable element itself?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I have a list of element. They are all have `draggable="true"` attribute and can fire `ondragenter` and `ondragover` event. In other words, they are all draggable and droppable.

The problem is, when I drag an element, its `ondragenter` event fires immediately. This is not what I expected.

How can I prevent the these events which I am dragging an element?

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll('.div');
var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    (function(j) {
        div[j].addEventListener('dragstart', handlDragStart);
        div[j].addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
        div[j].addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
    })(i)
}

function handlDragStart(ev) {
 ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
 ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
}

function handleDragEnter (ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
    ev.target.classList.add('enter');
 }

 function handleDragOver (ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 }
```

```css
.div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
}
.enter {
    border: 3px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="div" draggable="true">1</div>
    <div class="div" draggable="true">2</div>
    <div class="div" draggable="true">3</div>
    <div class="div" draggable="true">4</div>
    <div class="div" draggable="true">5</div>
</div>
```

I made this example.I expect that when I drag a rec into another rec, the latter get a red border. You can see when I start drag, the first rec get the red border immediately which means the `dragenter()` fires. How can I prevent it?

Comment: Can you share an example of what exactly you are doing?

Comment: @davidkonrad I edited the post and added code snippet

Comment: No solution ? i just came across this.. I mean besides making sure its not the same element as what was stored on dragstart... i don't see how else to prevent a drag enter into itself